# is iTunes connection a reliable method to check an iPhone is dead or alive?

Tags: iphone, itunes

I guess a turned on iPhone will always show up in iTunes when you plug it to a mac or PC (even if you need to unlock the passcode).  I sometimes need to known if an iPhone is dead inside or it's just the screen not showing image.

Comment: Theoretically, yes. Also, if you know the phone number associated with the phone, you could try calling it and see if it vibrates/rings.

Comment: Also, if you have an Apple Store nearby, make a Genius Bar appointment, take it in, and see if they can help you.